# Is it possible to ignore ssl verification for fetch api in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am using fetch API in react single page application, and I need to access a self-signed https microservice, it fails because of the SSL verification. Is it possible to ignore the verification? And how to do it?

Comment: In a test environment, or for any arbitrary browser visiting your site?

Comment: @t.niese, in a test environment.

Comment: If it is in an test eniroment, then you cann add this certificat to you browse, and then your browser won't complain about it anymore.

Answer (score 5):

No, this error is from your browser and cannot be avoided in JavaScript. You must either add the self-signed certificate to your root certificate repository on your local machine or obtain a valid signed certificate from a free service such as [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Could you link to the source where you got this information from please?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can relay the request via your own server. but some instance needs to have SSL enabled, if the app itself runs on HTTPS.

on the server-side you can ignore wrong certificates.
E.g.: https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/19#issuecomment-289709519