# fetch localhost without redirecting to https?

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, browser, https

In the development environment, I don't want to make things [complicated](https://web.dev/how-to-use-local-https/) by using [https and SSL/STL certifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67117016/3552975).

I learned how to prevent [Google Chrome from redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66555091/3552975), and a JSON object returned after entering `http:/localhost:105/hello/` into the Chrome address bar.

What confused me is that the following does not work in the browser console(Inspect->Console) for https pages:

```
const url = new URL('http://localhost:105/hello/');
fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(json => console.log(json))
```

The error reads that:

> GET https://localhost:105/hello/ net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
> at :1:1

And adding parameter `{redirect: 'manual'}` in the fetch method doesn't help.

Thanks to [@novavanity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20664059/novavanity). It does work on the page with the url http://localhost:105/hello/

I don't know why and how the http was redirected to https? How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `fetch()` in the browser, it automatically uses the HTTPS protocol if the current page is loaded over HTTPS. This is probably why you are getting the

> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

error when trying to access http://localhost:105/hello/ using `fetch()`.

To prevent `fetch()` from using HTTPS, you can use the base option in the Request object that you pass to `fetch()`:

```
const url = new URL('http://localhost:105/hello/');
const options = {
  base: 'http://localhost:105/'
};

fetch(url, options).then(response => response.json()).then(json => console.log(json))
```

Comment: You are right. It is because of the current page's https, but the base option seems does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS happens due to a 307 error code (internal redirect). You can check this in the 'Network' tab of Chrome's Developer tools panel.

[Where the network tab is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeimM.png)

So, if you had previously had the URL as HTTPS, you might want to clear your cache on Chrome and restart the app. Hope that helps.